# Why does nothing show up in the Compositing tab?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I am trying to follow Blender Guru's beginner tutorial.

He went to the *Compositor* tab and was using it to Denoise an image but when I got there, no nodes show up.

Can you guys help?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

In the upper menu, you need to check *Use Nodes* **✓**
Then it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
In my case, even when I press on "Use Nodes", nothing appears. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Joana for new questions use the ask question box at the top of the page.

Comment: @Joana You can of course add any nodes manually through the add menu :). In this case "Render Layers" and a "Composite" node.

Comment: lol.. why is that not on by default? are there other more common options than nodes?

Comment: @CromeX It's just a UI choice. I enabled it by default in my startup file :).

Answer (score 1):

You can also click the *View* menu (on same row as *Use Nodes*) then *View All*.