# Blender Composition not showing image

Tags: rendering

I'm relatively new to blender, working on a tutorial that's supposed to train me on how to use it on youtube.

One part doesn't seem to match up as you'll see. Here's what you see on the tutorial when he clicks "Composition"

[image]

it has this modal that's supposed to help with denoising the image.

Here's how it looks on my end, from the layout

[image]

with my donut so far, and when I click composition I'm missing that modal

[image]

I'm guessing you can add it, I just don't know how to.

My current version is 2.8.2

[image]

Comment: Disabled by default. There is a "Use Nodes" checkbox at the top of the compositor window... click it.

Comment: Just to illustrate what brockmann suggested: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164411/